# C++ convertStringToByteArray to Delphi convertStringToByteArray

Tags: c++, delphi, byte, data-conversion, globalplatform

Im trying to use the [GlobalPlatform library](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform) from Karsten Ohme (kaoh) in Delphi. Thanks to the help of some people here on stackoverflow i got it parially working and i am able to setup a connection to the cardreader. Now i am trying to select an AID, and therefore i need to pass the AID as array of Bytes to the function.

I use the GPShell (the commandline tool that uses the same library) source code as a reference to help me translate the functions. There i found the convertStringToByteArray function, which takes a string and converts it to a array of Bytes.

The original C++ function:

```
static int convertStringToByteArray(TCHAR *src, int destLength, BYTE *dest)
{
    TCHAR *dummy;
    unsigned int temp, i = 0;
    dummy = malloc(destLength*2*sizeof(TCHAR) + sizeof(TCHAR));
    _tcsncpy(dummy, src, destLength*2+1);
    dummy[destLength*2] = _T('\0');
    while (_stscanf(&(dummy[i*2]), _T("%02x"), &temp) > 0)
    {
        dest[i] = (BYTE)temp;
        i++;
    }
    free(dummy);
    return i;
}
```

and i tried to write a similar procedure in Delphi, i tried to convert the string in two ways - the first (Literally) converts every character (treated as HEX) to integer. The second way uses Move:

```
procedure StrToByteArray(Input: AnsiString; var Bytes: array of Byte; Literally: Boolean = false);
var
  I, B : Integer;
begin
  if Literally then
  begin
    for I := 0 to Length(Input) -1 do
    if TryStrToInt('$' + Input[I +1], B) then
      Bytes[I] := Byte(B)
    else
      Bytes[I] := Byte(0);
  end else
    Move(Input[1], Bytes[0], Length(Input));
end;
```

But i keep getting a

> (6A82: The application to be selected could not be found.)

error, when i try to select AID

> A000000003000000

I know i am trying to select the right AID, because when i use this same AID with GPShell - i get a successful response. So i am not sure if the problem is in my String to Byte array procedure, or maybe somewhere else.

When i use breakpoints, and i try to convert the string to bytes literally i get

```
(10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

in the debugger. But when i try with Move (or ORD) i get

```
(65, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 51, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48)
```

I also tried to convert the string to bytes online with various websites, and these give me another result

```
(41, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 33, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30)
```

So i am a bit lost in trying to find out what im doing wrong, is the problem in my string to bytes conversion - or do i need to look somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original C++ code parses **pairs of hex digits** into bytes:

`A000000003000000` -> `A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00`

But your Delphi code is parsing **individual hex digits** into bytes instead:

`A000000003000000` -> `A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Try this instead:

```
procedure StrToByteArray(Input: AnsiString; var Bytes: TBytes; Literally: Boolean = false);
var
  I, B : Integer;
begin
  if Literally then
  begin
    SetLength(Bytes, Length(Input) div 2);
    for I := 0 to Length(Bytes)-1 do
    begin
      if not TryStrToInt('$' + Copy(Input, (I*2)+1, 2), B) then
        B := 0;
      Bytes[I] := Byte(B);
    end;
  end else
  begin
    SetLength(Bytes, Length(Input));
    Move(Input[1], Bytes[0], Length(Input));
  end:
end;
```

That being said, Delphi has its own [`HexToBin()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.HexToBin) functions for parsing hex strings into byte arrays. You don't need to write your own parser, eg:

```
procedure StrToByteArray(Input: AnsiString; var Bytes: TBytes; Literally: Boolean = false);
begin
  if Literally then
  begin
    SetLength(Bytes, Length(Input) div 2);
    HexToBin(PAnsiChar(Input), PByte(Bytes), Length(Bytes));
  end else
  begin
    SetLength(Bytes, Length(Input));
    Move(Input[1], Bytes[0], Length(Input));
  end:
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This works directly as expected! You made my day! (Again)!